# Queries in Slow query logs, where it lock time is too high

Tags: mysql

I was looking at slow query logs and I found following query that is taking too much time

```
# Query_time: 4875.960250  Lock_time: 4819.281516 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
use mydb;
SET timestamp=1358591898;
SELECT `Currency`.`rate` 
FROM `currencies` AS `Currency`   
WHERE `Currency`.`currency` = 'usd '    
LIMIT 1;
```

What should I need to do to optimize query time, and how lock time should be minimized?

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing what you can try, if table is type MyISAM, change it to InnoDB, InnoDB supports locking on the row level, means if you are updating table, other queries don't have to wait till operation is finished, if are not accessing same row.

Otherwise query looks simple, I wouldn't expect currencies table will change very often.

If this not the case, check if caching is configured correctly for example with https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer